# Using PrettyFaces action programatically on p:menuitem

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I have a PrimeFaces 6.0 menu item hooked to PrettyFaces 3.3.3 like this:

```
<h:form id="nav"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:prime="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<prime:panelMenu label="Menu">
    <prime:submenu label="SubMenu">
        <prime:menuitem value="page" action="pretty:page"/>
    </prime:submenu>
</prime:panelMenu>
</h:form>
```

This works fine. But how can I build the menu in Java and achieve the same?

This page

```
<prime:panelMenu model="#{bean.navMenu}" id="leftNavMenu"/>
```

gets me the menu structure as expected, but I don't know how to set the action for each menu item.

```
public MenuModel getNavMenu() {
    MenuModel model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    DefaultSubMenu subMenu = new DefaultSubMenu("sub menu");
    DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem("page");
    // something is missing here
    subMenu.addElement(menuItem);
    model.addElement(subMenu);
    return model;
}
```

There is no `setAction` method on `DefaultMenuItem`.

I tried these:

- `menuItem.setUrl("pretty:page");` --- uses `pretty:page` as the URL and the browser complains that the address was not understood (understandably)
- `menuItem.setHref("pretty:page");` --- as with `setUrl`
- `menuItem.setCommand("pretty:page");` gets a `NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` in the server log
- `menuItem.setOutcome("pretty:page");` gets a URL with a trailing `?com.ocpsoft.mappingId=page`, so PrettyFaces does not seem to do its magic, and in turn the page crashes because it does not get its parameters mapped / injected as expected.

How can I set the action from code?

Using setCommand gets this stack trace in the server logs:

```
[2016-07-28T14:55:42.198-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1469735742198] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.findMenuitem(BaseMenuRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.decode(BaseMenuRenderer.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:831)
...
```

Comment: Did you try: `org.primefaces.component.menuitem.UIMenuItem`. It has `setAction` for sure.

Comment: Does it work doing this in a `p:commandLink`?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, it does, at least, when I add it right to the page. (I adjusted the question.) But then that works also for the menu.

Comment: Yes, but does it work setting it in code for a `p:commandLink`? And you can debug what happens when doing a `menuItem.setCommand("pretty:page");` Where does the NFE occur (stacktrace) and why is the one with the setOutcome wrong? Seems like something adds the trailing part and it is not PrimeFaces.

Comment: @Kukeltje The code magically works if I use `setCommand` on the menu items and then call `generateUniqueIds()` on the `MenuModel` before returning it.

Comment: Hmmm... strange. Great it works. Did the stacktrace help you find a solution in this direction? Was the NumberFormatException related to this? Then it might also fail in other situations. But it succeeds in the showcase (only without PrettyFaces). Unfortunately I won't try to find the real reason it failed for you since it works and there is otherwise no incentive for me. Cheers

Comment: @Kukeltje Fair enough. Thanks for your help. You asking about the stack trace got me on the right track. I googled `org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer` and came across posts struggling with ID problems and someone mentioned `generateUniqueIds()`. If it breaks again, I'll throw out the legacy XML from which the menu is generated now and just put the `<pamelMenu>` in the page.

Comment: You  can create an answer to this question yourself. And did you know you can also create the facelets xml in a string  and use that in your site? Look for faceletsresolver in stackoverflow

Comment: PrettyFaces 3.3.3 is extremely old at this point. The version numbers are a bit confusing, which is about to be fixed, but PrettyFaces is now part of the OCPsoft Rewrite project, so the version should be 2.0.12.Final: http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/#section-4

Comment: @Lincoln Yes, I know, thanks... I am upgrading an old code base and replacing IceFaces with PrimeFaces is the first step cause that seems to block upgrading other libraries. Eventually I'll also get to upgrade PrettyFaces to Rewrite.

Comment: Great! Just wanted to make sure you knew. We are actually about to, in the next week, release version 3.4.0.Final of rewrite (We were going to release version 3.0 anyway, but we decided to version bump to 3.4.0 to alleviate confusion.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anybody else comes across this problem: use `command` in the menu items, and make sure you call `generateUniqueIds` on the whole menu:

```
public MenuModel getNavMenu() {
    MenuModel model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    DefaultSubMenu subMenu = new DefaultSubMenu("sub menu");
    DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem("page");
    menuItem.setCommand("pretty:page");
    subMenu.addElement(menuItem);
    model.addElement(subMenu);
    model.generateUniqueIds();
    return model;
}
```